# How to set state in React after a timeout?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am creating a simple roulette wheel in React and when I attempt to set the state `spinning` to false at the end of the function being run it does not change.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

const numbers = [
  0, 32, 15, 19, 4, 21, 2, 25, 17, 34, 6, 27, 13, 36, 11, 30, 8, 23, 10, 5, 24,
  16, 33, 1, 20, 14, 31, 9, 22, 18, 29, 7, 28, 12, 35, 3, 26,
];

const green = [0];

const red = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 12, 14, 16, 18, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 30, 32, 34, 36];

const black = [
  2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 11, 13, 15, 17, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 29, 31, 33, 35,
];

const RouletteWheel = () => {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);
  const [spinning, setSpinning] = useState(false);

  const getRandomNumber = () => {
    return numbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length)];
  };

  const spin = () => {
    const num = getRandomNumber();
    let numColor = "";
    const i = numbers.length * 2 + numbers.indexOf(num) + 1;
    for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setSpinning(true);
        if (green.includes(numbers[j % numbers.length])) {
          numColor = "green";
        } else if (red.includes(numbers[j % numbers.length])) {
          numColor = "red";
        } else if (black.includes(numbers[j % numbers.length])) {
          numColor = "black";
        }
        document.getElementById("numberDisp").style.color = numColor;
        setNumber(numbers[j % numbers.length]);
      }, j * (j * 1.25));
    }
    setSpinning(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className="roulette">
      <h1 id="numberDisp">{number}</h1>
      <button onClick={spin} disabled={spinning}>
        {spinning ? "Spinning..." : "Spin the wheel!"}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default RouletteWheel;
```

I've tried moving around the setSpinning but nothing has fixed it

Comment: this will set `spinning` to `false` when the timeout starts, and back to `true` when it's finished, which seems backwards. Remember that the code inside the `setTimeout` runs only after the delay, whereas the code directly after runs straight away.

Comment: did not know this very new to react (as you might be able to tell) but thank you very much for this explanation

Comment: happy to help - but note that `setTimeout` is a core Javascript API, and nothing in itself to do with React

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just added `useEffect` to your code, added an useEffect hook that listens for changes to the `spinning` state and executes any additional code you provide once the state has been updated. i also moved the `setSpinning(false)` call inside the loop to ensure that it's executed only once the loop has completed. Calling `setSpinning(false)` immediately after the loop will not guarantee that the state has been updated by the time you call it. You can use the `useEffect` hook to wait for the state to update before executing additional code.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    
    const numbers = [
      0, 32, 15, 19, 4, 21, 2, 25, 17, 34, 6, 27, 13, 36, 11, 30, 8, 23, 10, 5, 24,
      16, 33, 1, 20, 14, 31, 9, 22, 18, 29, 7, 28, 12, 35, 3, 26,
    ];
    
    const green = [0];
    
    const red = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 12, 14, 16, 18, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 30, 32, 34, 36];
    
    const black = [
      2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 11, 13, 15, 17, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 29, 31, 33, 35,
    ];
    
    const RouletteWheel = () => {
      const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);
      const [spinning, setSpinning] = useState(false);
    
      const getRandomNumber = () => {
        return numbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length)];
      };
    
      useEffect(() => {
        if (!spinning) {
          // additional code to execute once the spinning state has been updated
        }
      }, [spinning]);
    
      const spin = () => {
        const num = getRandomNumber();
        let numColor = "";
        const i = numbers.length * 2 + numbers.indexOf(num) + 1;
        for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
          setTimeout(() => {
            setSpinning(true);
            if (green.includes(numbers[j % numbers.length])) {
              numColor = "green";
            } else if (red.includes(numbers[j % numbers.length])) {
              numColor = "red";
            } else if (black.includes(numbers[j % numbers.length])) {
              numColor = "black";
            }
            document.getElementById("numberDisp").style.color = numColor;
            setNumber(numbers[j % numbers.length]);
            if (j === i - 1) {
              // last iteration, so set spinning to false
              setSpinning(false);
            }
          }, j * (j * 1.25));
        }
      };
    
      return (
        <div className="roulette">
          <h1 id="numberDisp">{number}</h1>
          <button onClick={spin} disabled={spinning}>
            {spinning ? "Spinning..." : "Spin the wheel!"}
          </button>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default RouletteWheel;
```

Comment: You should add an explanation of what you've changed to your answer otherwise it's just a rarely-useful code-dump.

Comment: The useEffect is the wrong solution for this imo. It serves no purpose since you can call the same function immediately after `setSpinning(false)`.  The function executed in the useEffect might be dependent on other state (introducing more dependencies) which will make the useEffect fire more than intended (and likely lead to unnecessary conditional logic).

Comment: İ tested it before putting my answer here bro it works